# What type of CA is "Management CA" in EJBCA?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

In the EJBCA documentation I found a CA named *Management CA*. I would like to know what type of CA this CA is. Is it a RootCA or subCA?

Answer (score 2):

EJBCA requires client certificates to allow administrators to log in to its user interface. The Management CA issues these certificates as well as the default TLS certificate for the interface.